# unable to start mongodb local server

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb .. when i tried running mongodb local server with `mongod` command it failed to run and threw this error..

```
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongod --help for help and startup options
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 MongoDB starting : pid=1782 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit 

** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
**       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations

Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 db version v1.6.3, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 git version: nogitversion
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 sys info: Linux vernadsky 2.6.24-27-server #1 SMP Fri Mar 12 01:45:06 UTC 2010 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_42
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten]   addr already in use
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 dbexit: 

Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush oplog...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51     closeAllFiles() finished

Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I tried deleting `mongod.lock` file... 
I ran `mongod --repair`..
I also changed permissions to `mongod.lock` file.

but nothing seems to work.. it keeps showing the same error.. 
what should i do.?

I also have installed git version 1.7.4.1
but it shows nogitversion in error..

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798549/why-cant-i-start-the-mongodb

Answer (score 177):

Try:

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo mongod
```

To stop current active mongodb service, allowing you to then start a new one

Comment: i also got the service message but decided to ignore it and try restarting again with "sudo mongod" and after it finally worked

Comment: Shouldn't this be mongod (not mongodb)?  Based on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#stop-mongodb

Comment: `sudo service mongodb stop` worked for me on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: There is no service command on OS X. If you have mongo installed via homebrew you can use `brew services`. (via http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155715/sudo-service-command-not-found-when-installing-mongodb.)

Comment: To see a solution on Mac OSX for stopping the mongod service, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428123/mongodb-wont-start

Comment: @HarshaMV ` brew services stop <formula> `

Comment: For mac homebrew use @HarshaMV comment "brew services stop mongodb". Thanks Harsha

Comment: On Mac without Homebrew: 1) Open Activity Monitor and find 'mongod' under Process Name in the CPU pane. 2) Stop the 'mongod' process. 3) Restart the Mongo service in the Terminal with 'mongod'

Answer (score 153):

Don't kill the process using the -9 signal as it would cause damage: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-SendingaUnixINTorTERMsignal

Use `sudo killall -15 mongod` instead

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Comment: `killall mongod` does the same thing also. the `-15` tells `killall` to send a SIGTERM signal, which it does by default.

Comment: Actually doing a killall actually worked for me instead of trying to stop the service. So, even though it does not answer the questions. That was useful

Answer (score 60):

> Andreas Jung:
>
> "Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
>
> is self-speaking.
>
> Another instance of mongod is already running and allocating the MongoDB default port which is 27017.
>
> Either kill the other process or use a different port."

In this case, type the following command

```
ps wuax | grep mongo
```

You should see something that looks like this

```
User           31936   0.5 0.4 2719784 35624   ?? S     7:34pm   0:09.98 mongod
User           31945   0.0 0.0 2423368   184 s000 R+   8:24pm   0:00.00 grep mongo
```

Now enter the kill command for the mongod instance (31936 in this case):

```
kill 31936
```

Answer (score 29):

> Sat Jun 25 09:38:51 [initandlisten]
>   listen(): bind() failed errno:98
>   Address already in use for socket:
>   0.0.0.0:27017

is self-speaking.

Another instance of mongod is already running and allocating the MongoDB default port which is 27017.

Either kill the other process or use a different port.

Comment: Found this on getting started page...**When mongodb** **is installed** **via aptitude it is already running (so in the example you do not** **need to start it). Then just type:
$ mongo**.. since i personally dint start mongod and i was following the quickstart tutorial .. i dint knew it was already running...

Comment: @Sakti: Yea, it is already running for me! I guess i did via aptitude. Thx!

Answer (score 29):

Find out from netstat which process is running mongodb port (27017)

command:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :27017
```

Output will be:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:* 
LISTEN      6432/mongod
```

In my case  "6432" is the pid, it may be different in your case.
Then kill that process using following command:

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 25):

Use:

```
sudo killall mongod
```

It will stop the server.

Then restart `mongod` by:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

it should work.

Answer (score 23):

You already have a process running. You can kill it with the command :

```
killall mongod
```

Answer (score 15):

You want to do `killall -15 mongod` because it is still running: `Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017`.

Then you can run `mongod` again.

Comment: Why not simply `killall mongod`?

Comment: ```No matching processes belonging to you were found```

Comment: Then mongod must not be a process running. Maybe the address is being used by a different process

Answer (score 7):

Try a different port if you can't find any current running processes or killing them doesn't work. For example, try 27018 because the default is 27017.

```
mongod  --port 27018
```

I found this out with the command, `mongod --help`

Answer (score 7):

I suggest use instead:

`$sudo service mongodb stop`

That could work.

Answer (score 6):

Try either killall -15 mongod/ killall mongod
Even after this if this doesnt work then remove the db storage folder by typing the following commands
sudo rm -rf /data/db
sudo mkdir /data/db
sudo chmod 777 /data/db

Answer (score 5):

OS X.
**Activity Monitor**, 
look for **mongod**, 
cross it .
then run again mongod.
problem Solved.

Comment: OP does not specify the OS but the log files clearly denote Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and type:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Then enter:

```
mongod
```

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB unable to start is mainly due to unclean shutdown. To remedy, delete the mongod.lock file.  This file is located in the data folder.

Find out where your data folder is by looking in the mongodb.conf or mongod.conf file. (Conf file under /etc on Linux systems.)

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
```

For example using the above configuration, the file is at /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock.  Simply remove it and restart mongodb.

Comment: This has happened to me more than once, especially on cloud servers that have been "hard reset" when unresponsive.  It is an easy fix and should be a top answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem were I tried to open a new instance of mongod and it said it was already running.

I checked the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) and it said to type

```
mongo
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue. Though the `mongodb` service is not running, the log showed `address already in use` message.

```
 $netstat -tulpn | grep :27017
```

returns nothing

On further analysis found that the issue was due to lock file. The service is running fine, after deleting the lock file and restarting it.

```
$grep "dbpath" /etc/mongodb.conf

dbpath =/var/lib/mongodb

$ls /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

$service mongod start
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for logs at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log and try to deduce the error. In my case it was

Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted

Deleted /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try

/usr/lib/mongodb/mongod.exe --dbpath c:data\db

--dbpath (should be followed by the path of your db)

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that the server is already running. Please check it by the command **mongo** is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue in **Windows**, the below steps work for me:

For example mongoDB version 3.6 is installed, and the install path of MongoDB is "D:\Program Files\MongoDB".

Create folder D:\mongodb\logs, then create file mongodb.log inside this folder.

Run cmd.exe as **administrator**,

```
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>taskkill /F /IM mongod.exe
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod.exe --logpath D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath D:\mongodb\data --directoryperdb --serviceName MongoDB --remove
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --logpath "D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log" --logappend --dbpath "D:\mongodb\data" --directoryperdb --serviceName "MongoDB" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB" --install
```

Remove these two files `mongod.lock` and `storage.bson` under the folder "D:\mongodb\data".

Then type `net start MongoDB` in the cmd using administrator privilege, the issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It shows error listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
i.e. 27017 address is already in used by some other service.
 please check this by 
"netstat -apt| grep "27017""
command

Answer (score 0):

(If your're using linux,) if

```
mongod --shutdown --config=path/to/your/configFile.conf
```

or

```
mongod --repair --config=path/to/your/configFile.conf
```

didn't fix the issue, **logout and re-login**. That solved my problem.

Or you can kill the process manually from terminal, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the same error is showed in logs when you're missing LC_ALL environment setting. It's confusing, but you may execute `mongo` client to see that it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running mongo for first time you might wanna set the path first

```
mongod --dbpath <path to the directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Killing process did not solve my issue. 
My **mac** had crashed and on restart some of lock files (mongod.lock, WiredTiger.lock) were present in mongo dbPath. I moved these files to different folder (I did not delete to avoid more issues) and then it worked.
On successul star, I deleted the moved lock files.