# Mongodb won't start

Tags: macos, mongodb

I installed MongoDB using the Mac Homebrew command but when I run `mongod`

It's not recognized my my terminal :/

If I type in `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin` then run `mongod` it starts up but quickly exits

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=59800 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Kevin-Tucks-MacBook-Pro.local
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] git version: 329f3c47fe8136c03392c8f0e548506cb21f8ebf
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 2.38
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 dbexit: 
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I've tried restarting my shell but if I try to run `mongod` again, it comes back as unrecognised and requires me to retype in `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin`.

Comment: Something is already using the ports, that mongo wants to use. Maybe previous mongo instance is running. Use `netcat` or similar tool to know the PID of that process.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with netcat but I tried netstat and im getting.. netstat -an | grep 27017
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.27017        *.*                    LISTEN     
84de1dfcd2270d97 stream      0      0 84de1dfcd318fb37                0                0                0 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: Have you tried to start mongo client to connect to localhost? Maybe mongod is already started and you just need to connect to it.

Comment: That output is actually telling you that mongodb is already running, try running the console and connect

Comment: Other posters are correct - you already have a something running on 27017 most likely another mongod. What does

    `ps -ef | grep mongod`

show?

Answer (score 80):

Kyle: "It looks like mongo is already running or another process is using port 27017"

In this case, type the following command

```
ps wuax | grep mongo
```

You should see something that looks like this

```
User           31936   0.5 0.4 2719784 35624   ?? S     7:34pm   0:09.98 mongod
User           31945   0.0 0.0 2423368   184 s000 R+   8:24pm   0:00.00 grep mongo
```

Now enter the kill command for the mongod instance (31936 in this case):

```
kill 31936
```

Comment: Had to use "sudo kill pid"

Comment: Most answers to this problem are missing this part, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I just installed brew on osx (10.9.3),  mongod (2.6.1) and had the same problem.  Def not running a second copy.

```
$ lsof -i | grep 2701
```

shows no open port.

I found the following helped.

The default config file brew writes (/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf) contains the line:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,<my-machine>.local
```

If you edit this file and change the line to either of the following:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
or
bind_ip = <my-machine>.local
```

Then restart the service with the command below, it should startup as expected.

```
$ brew services restart mongodb
```

You can check for success or failure by tailing the logfile in another window while starting

```
$ tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

It appears it is trying to open both of the addresses listed here and they both resolve to 127.0.0.1 so we always get a failure when it tries to open the second port and then shuts the whole thing down.

Answer (score 3):

> Sun Jan 20 18:59:25 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use Sun Jan 20
>   18:59:25 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48
>   Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017 Sun Jan 20 18:59:25
>   [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use

It looks like mongo is already running or another process is using port `27017`

Answer (score 1):

this solution work for me. I'm using mongodb version 3.2

i set path to,

```
/usr/local/bin
```

and i make mongodb data directory to /data/db and set permission to myown account. This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-x/) from mkyong is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For any of the people who land up here, this was resolved (at least on my end) by stopping the already running `mongodb` service:

`brew services stop mongodb`

and then running `mongod`.

Answer (score 0):

For mongod not being in your PATH, it looks like the logic to support that was tweaked a couple of times since the version you're on.  If you upgrade, that issue might well be fixed automatically.

- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/9348b1030b53558ae9311ccd528888a28fade0c4#Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/475e63dc7e7574bc5b8e4d037b6dded461cab727#Library/Formula/mongodb.rb

As others have already said, the error it's giving indicates that another process is already using the configured port.  One possibility is that in the past, you ran the command that Homebrew presented to you to install MongoDB as a LaunchAgent.  If that's the case, this command should undo that, allowing you to launch it from the command-line.

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

Comment: I tried hat command but I got an error 'launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/Keva161/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to unload'

It appears to be running a server automatically when I don't want it to  :/ Is there anyway to turn that off?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you do have Mongo installed as a service, but not at that location.  Mac OS X doesn't come with a particularly good UI for managing LaunchAgents/LaunchDaemons.  "man launchctl" will get you help on the command-line approach.  Lingon (currently $5) is a GUI app for managing them that makes it a lot easier.  http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/

Answer (score 0):

It won't permit killing when you configured autostart so remove the lock file and repair it (mac osx).

```
 cd /data/db
 rm mongod.lock
 sudo mongod --repair
```