# Cannot start MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, homebrew

This my 5th time installing MongoDB where it either only connects the first time or intermittently. The fifth time I tried with Homebrew.

Here are the two different errors I've gotten:

```
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=40879 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=CA17PCG8WP
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-18T01:19:21.746-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-10-18T01:19:21.747-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-18T01:19:21.747-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-18T01:19:22.124-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-18T01:19:22.124-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-10-18T01:19:22.125-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-10-18T01:19:22.126-0700 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname CA17PCG8WP: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

And:

```
2016-10-21T18:31:30.436-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2982 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=CA17PCG8WP
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-21T18:31:30.437-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-21T18:31:30.439-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (13) [1477099890:439019][2982:0x7fff73c85300], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2016-10-21T18:31:30.446-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied
2016-10-21T18:31:30.447-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 13: Permission denied, terminating
2016-10-21T18:31:30.447-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Can someone please either a) tell me what I'm doing wrong or b) tell me how to uninstall MongoDB and then install it properly?

**EDIT:**

I believe I already had read & write access to /data/db/, but I used `chmod` anyway. Here's proof I have access (right?):

```
whoami
this_user
ls -ld /data/
drwxr-xr-x  3 this_user  wheel  102 Oct 21 18:18 /data/
ls -ld /data/db/
drwxr-xr-x  16 this_user  wheel  544 Oct 21 18:31 /data/db/
```

And here's the error I'm still getting:

```
mongod
2016-10-22T12:10:26.301-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5912 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=CA17PCG8WP
2016-10-22T12:10:26.301-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-10-22T12:10:26.301-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-22T12:10:26.302-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-10-22T12:10:26.304-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (13) [1477163426:304329][5912:0x7fff73c85300], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2016-10-22T12:10:26.311-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied
2016-10-22T12:10:26.311-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 13: Permission denied, terminating
2016-10-22T12:10:26.311-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you a 'permission denied' error on the data directory. Make sure you've got the right permissions there. Either `chown` the directory (and parent) to your current user / group or adjust permissions with `chmod` to make sure you have both read and write access to /data/db.

**EDIT**

I forgot that on some systems, mongodb runs as the user `mongodb`.  Check `/etc/passwd` to see if there is a mongodb user, and if so make sure *that* user or group has write permissions.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't appear to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured it out. Some combination of these two fixes did it:

- [mongod HostnameCanonicalizationWorker error on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818009/mongod-hostnamecanonicalizationworker-error-on-os-x/36479026)
- [Mongodb wont start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428123/mongodb-wont-start)