# Starting mongod fails unless run as root

Tags: mongodb

I am able to start my mongo server with the following command:

```
[lucas@ecoinstance]~/node/nodetest2$ sudo mongod --dbpath /home/lucas/node/nodetest2/data
 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod-nodetest2.log                                  
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 10293
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

but when I try to remove the `sudo`, I get the following error:

```
[lucas@ecoinstance]~/node/nodetest2$ mongod --dbpath /home/lucas/node/nodetest2/
data --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod-nodetest2.log
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 10284
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Here is additional information:

```
[lucas@ecoinstance]~/node/nodetest2$ ls -l data/*
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 67108864 Jun  7 20:57 data/local.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Jun  7 20:57 data/local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb        6 Jun  7 20:57 data/mongod.lock
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 67108864 Jun  7 02:08 data/nodetest1.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Jun  7 02:08 data/nodetest1.ns
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 67108864 Jun  7 23:01 data/nodetest2.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Jun  7 23:01 data/nodetest2.ns

data/journal:
total 3145744
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Jun  7 23:01 j._0
-rw------- 1 root    root            88 Jun  7 23:01 lsn
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Jun  6 03:10 prealloc.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Jun  6 03:12 prealloc.2

[lucas@ecoinstance]~/node/nodetest2$ ls -l /etc/mongod.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 1701 May  5 15:07 /etc/mongod.conf

[lucas@ecoinstance]~/node/nodetest2$ ls -l /var/log/mongodb/
total 120
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 96801 Jun  7 05:48 mongod.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    15625 Jun  8 00:18 mongod-nodetest2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb  2805 Jun  7 20:38 mongod-nodetest2.log.2014-06-07T20-57-47
```

I cannot find a similar problem. What is the cause of this issue?

**Update**
Thanks to Asya's answer below, I ran a similar command, but changed the location of the log file to one which does not need root access privileges:

```
mongod --dbpath /home/lucas/node/nodetest2/data --fork --logpath /home/lucas/data/log/mongodb/mongod-nodetest2.log
```

I also encountered an issue where `mongod` was running in the background, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server). Stopping that process before running the above command worked for me.

Thanks Asya!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start mongod as user `xxx` then all the directories and files it needs to use must be owned by user `xxx` - in your case I see several files owned by `root` so mongod cannot manipulate those files.

Fix the permissions and make sure you never run `mongod` as root again.  Also, when you get an error from `mongod` looking in the log file will tell you exactly what caused an error.  (In all cases except where the file is not writable by the user `mongod` is running as).