# Can't start MongoDB on OSX

Tags: macos, mongodb, permissions

I'm trying to run MongoDB on OSX and encountering a common problem, Error with exit code 1.

Here's my very simple mongod.conf:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: ~/Documents/test/mongodb/mongodb.log

storage:
  directoryPerDB: true
  dbPath: ~/Documents/test/mongodb/mongodb_data
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background

net:
  port: 27017
```

I 777'd all the folders so there's no way it can be a permissions issue (right? :P)

```
mac$ ls -lah ~/Documents/test/mongodb/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   5 mac  staff   170B Dec  4 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 mac  staff   374B Dec  4 15:19 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 mac  staff   301B Dec  4 15:21 mongod.conf
-rwxrwxrwx   1 mac  staff     0B Dec  4 15:21 mongodb.log
drwxrwxrwx   2 mac  staff    68B Dec  4 15:18 mongodb_data
```

But it still gets this error code!

```
mac$ sudo mongod -f ~/Documents/test/mongodb/mongod.conf 
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 70062
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Things I've tried from other questions:

1. Apparently I shouldn't have to run this as sudo (?), I've tried both sudo and no sudo, same result
2. Could be a permissions issue ([Starting mongod fails unless run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101873/starting-mongod-fails-unless-run-as-root)) - well the mongodb_data directory and the conf and log are all 777 so can that really be the case? I've tried `chown` on all of them too but no effect.
3. Remove the pid location in your mongod.conf (done, doesn't have any effect) [Starting mongod fork, ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591101/starting-mongod-fork-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1)

Also:

- mongodb.log has nothing in it after multiple start attempts
- mongodb_data/ has nothing in it either (no .lock file or whatever, just empty)

Any ideas?

Comment: As a next step I would try running mongod without the config file. Running "mongod --dbpath DB_PATH", substituting DB_PATH for your actual dbpath. I would also use absolute paths rather than using "~" as the base for both log and dbpath.

Comment: Changing the paths to absolutes rather than relatives doesn't have any effect. However, calling the entire thing from the command line seems to work like: sudo mongod --dbpath /Users/mac/Documents/test/mongodb/mongodb_data/ --fork --logpath /Users/mac/Documents/test/mongodb/mongodb.log - but why not using a conf file?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably error with log file. It's strange that yours is 0 bytes.
Anyway you do not need to make 777 permissions, you do not need to run mongod with sudo on OSX system.
Try to do the following:

1. mkdir ~/sometest
2. cd ~/sometest
3. cp ~/Documents/test/mongodb/mongod.conf .
4. Replace systemLog path to mongodb.log, replace dbpath to data
5. mkdir data
6. Start mongod (mongod -f mongod.conf)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have tried this but get another error:
mac$ mkdir ~/sometest
mac$ cd ~/sometest/
mac$ cp ~/Documents/test/mongodb/mongod.conf .
mac$ vim mongod.conf 
mac$ mkdir data
mac$ mongod -f mongod.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 73375
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14 (Edit: it destroyed my formatting)

Comment: Check your config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476447/mongodb-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-14