# Mongodb service not running

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on this automatic drink dispenser and ran into an issue when I  downloaded the Mongo 3.0.7 I tried to run it but I keep getting this error:

I got the idea from this website. http://yujiangtham.com/2014/05/30/build-your-very-own-drink-mixing-robot-part-2/

> 2016-02-02T15:56:42.585-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen():
>   bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket:
>   0.0.0.0:27017
>
> 2016-02-02T15:56:42.585-0500 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already
>   in use    2016-02-02T15:56:42.593-0500 W -        [initandlisten]
>   Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
>
> 2016-02-02T15:56:42.593-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:35
>   Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already
>   running?, terminating
>
> 2016-02-02T15:56:42.593-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc:
>   100

I need help on how to run this. The website I'm using as a reference is
http://yujiangtham.com/2014/05/30/build-your-very-own-drink-mixing-robot-part-2/

Comment: Possible duplicate. Here's is the link for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server

Answer (score 8):

It is stating that Mongo is already running. If you are certain it is not, then the lock file still exists from a previous unclean shutdown.

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

if that returns nothing, it will mean the lock file still exists. looking at your error, the file is `/data/db/mongod.lock`

```
rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

Should get rid of it so you'll be able to start the mongo service running again.

Comment: What if `ps aux | grep mongo` does return something? Mine did, then running `rm /data/db/mongod.lock` did nothing.
Had to reboot to fix the issue.

Comment: It means that mongo is running and there would be another reason why you weren't able to connect to it.

Comment: Why not force kill the process using `pkill` if mongod is still running, assuming that nothing important is being processed?

Answer (score 5):

Try running `pkill mongod` to kill the process