# Cannot start Mongo DB server on MAC

Tags: mongodb

I sometimes can start the `mongodb server` and sometimes I cannot. What is the real problem with my `mongodb server`. I am using `Mac` and I am getting this problem for the first time.

I tried to `kill` the `mongodb` process but it didn't help me.

Any possible solutions would be highly appreciated.

The error I am getting is below.

[image]

For killing the process, I tried to kill 27017 and it says no process found.

Comment: Looks like you try to start when there is already a mongo instance in the background, try to kill it with `-9`. Also can you put the text rather than the image?

Comment: @buræquete when I tried to kill mongodb, it says not process found. As in the above picture, the pid is 31252. When I tried to kill it, is says no any process found.

Comment: How about rather than killing manually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625337/3641067)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to start mongodb local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing port and PID. When you kill 27017, you send the SIGKILL signal to a process whose PID is 27017. However, unless there is a coincidence, mongod does not need to have that PID. 27017 is the default port for mongod instances.

To kill it properly do the following:

`ps -edf | grep mongod` --> get the PID of the mongod process

Then:

```
kill -SIGKILL <pid>
```

Then start it again.