# mongoid connection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've been trying to use Mongoid with Rails on Ubuntu. Mongodb was working fine for me with rails app 3.0 to 3.2,

today suddenly,  i am getting error "/home/pravinmishra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:413:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)"

Many times i face this issues, and below commands works for me.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair
sudo start mongodb
sudo status mongodb
```

but today i have not luck.

Previous couple of day back i changed my etc/hosts file and added 27.0.0.1 localhost.me

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.me:3000 localhost ubuntu
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
127.0.0.1 localhost.me locahost ubuntu
```

I thought, this creating problem. to over come i changed mongoid.config file localhost to 
localhost.me, but still getting error "/home/pravinmishra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:413:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost.me:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)"

mongoid.yml file

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  allow_dynamic_fields: false

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: xxx_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: xxx_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
 # host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
 # port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
 # username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
 # password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
 # database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>


 # set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance..!!

Comment: please post your mongoid.yml config file where you have defined the database connection configurations

Comment: defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  allow_dynamic_fields: false
  
development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: kidslink_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: kidslink_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
 # host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
 # port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
 # username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
 # password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
 # database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  
  
  # set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>

Comment: @ abhash, tks for quick reply. i edited question and added mongoid.yml file. Once take a look..!

Comment: From ubuntu, if you type in "mongo" does it connect to mongo's console shell?

Comment: @ Jesse , Getting same error. MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
connecting to: test
Mon Jul  9 22:47:06 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed

Comment: @PravinMishra Excellent! This means your error is not rails or mongodb related. Instead, it's proving that mongodb is not starting up. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798549/why-cant-i-start-the-mongodb and if not, ask your question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/hosts` file is broken

```
27.0.0.1 localhost.me:3000 localhost ubuntu
```

1. Your IP is incorrect. `localhost` is at 127.0.0.1, not 27.0.0.1
2. You can't put port numbers into this file. Think of `hosts` as a local DNS override.

Because Mongoid looks at 27.0.0.1 for a running MongoDB, it can't find one. And fails to connect.

Comment: hey,it's 127.0.0.1 localhost.me:3000 localhost ubuntu only. i did mistake when post question. I edited. sorry for that.

Comment: Then your MongoDB is probably not starting correctly. Please take a look at your `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Comment: and there is a typo `locahost` next to the line in question