# mongo server issue when restart the mongo process

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, storage-engines, wiredtiger

Mongo process started by normal user, then server has been rebooted.
After rebooting the server, when tried to start the mongod with the same user getting permission denied.
I checked in the log file, username got changed to root user.

The error message is

> Assertion: 28595: 13 : Permission denied exception in initAndListen:
>   28595 13: Permission denied, terminating dbexit: rc:100

In log file

```
1 root      root      256 WiredtigerLog4.log
1 mongodb   mongodb   256 WiredtigerLog3.log
1 mongodb   mongodb   256 WiredtigerLog2.log
1 mongodb   mongodb   256 WiredtigerLog1.log
```

My question How the user name changed to root

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798549/why-cant-i-start-the-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same issue with a mount disk. Make sure you change folder group and permission of your mongo data directory to mongod.

```
delete pid from /var/run/mongodb/mongoX.pid
chown -R mongod:mongod /<mongodatadirectory>/
chmod 775 -R /<mongodatadirectory>/
```

service mongod restart \sysvinit